# I would like to delete an item off my todo list and my object array at the same time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my code set up to be able to delete an item on the HTML side of things but after I add a new item the old item appears due to it not being deleted from my array I made. I would like to delete the array item associated with the list item I deleted.

HTML

```
<div class="list-content">
  <ul id="display_list">
    <li class="item">
      <img src="./img/icons/checked.svg">
      <p class="text">Take car to get oil change</p>
      <img id="trash" src="./img/icons/trash.svg"
         onclick="trashClicked(this)">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
let listItems = [];

function addItem() {
    let input = $('#item_input').val();

    let tempobj = {};
    tempobj.listname = input;
    listItems.push(tempobj);

    $('#item_input').val('');
    printmypage();
};

function printmypage() {
    $('#display_list').html('');
    for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i ++) {
        $('#display_list').append(`

                     <li class="item">
                       <img src=${unchecked}>
                       <p class="text">${listItems[i].listname}</p>
                       <img id="trash" src="./img/icons/trash.svg"
                          onclick="trashClicked(this)">
                     </li>

      `);
    };
};

function trashClicked(el) {
    console.log(listItems[1]);

    console.log(el);
    $(el).parent().remove();


};
```

I would like it when I click my trash svg icon in the function trashClicked() to delete that item in my listItems array. So when I go to add the next item it doesn't have it in my array.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of `el` using jQuery's `.index()` function (on the li element, which is its parent, or grandparent in my example). Then, with the value of the index, you call [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on the array.

Here you can see it in action (I call $(el).parent().parent() because I wrapped the remove button inside a div):

```js
let listItems = [{listname: 'Take car to get oil change'}];
printmypage();

function addItem() {
    let input = $('#item_input').val();

    let tempobj = {};
    tempobj.listname = input;
    listItems.push(tempobj);

    $('#item_input').val('');
    printmypage();
};

function printmypage() {
    $('#display_list').html('');
    for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i ++) {
        $('#display_list').append(`

                     <li class="item">
                       <div class="text">${listItems[i].listname}
                       <button onclick="trashClicked(this)">x</button>
                       </div>
                     </li>

      `);
    };
};

function trashClicked(el) {

    listItems.splice($(el).parent().parent().index(), 1);
    $(el).parent().parent().remove();
    
    printmypage();

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="item_input"/>
<button type="button" onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
<div class="list-content">
  <ul id="display_list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was trying to do.